# Xcode - Constraints on iPad - Landscape vs Portrait

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, autolayout

I can't seem to figure out constraints and auto layout.How can I have the spacing between two objects be different on the iPad when in landscape and portrait.

I placed to UIViews side by side. When in portrait I would like the spacing between them to be 40 but when in landscape it can be larger because there is more width.

This is what it looks like in portrait mode. Which I am happy with.
[image: Portrait]

And here it is in landscape. As you can see it doesn't seem to fill the screen as well and there ends up being a lot of empty space.
[image: Landscape]

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to pin it to the to the bottom and their respective sides.

View 1:

- Leading: 30
- Bottom: 25

View 2:

- Trailing: 30
- Bottom: 25

I used a >= constraint for the space between them (>= 5). If I increased the constant on any of these constraints the views would overlap. It's not the best situation because I still have a lot of empty space in landscape mode but it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

you can click the small + icon next to the constraint value and select different values for another size class.

or you can change the constraint value in code depending on your orientation.

or you can add extra constraints with lower priority and then increase the priority once you are in landscape mode.

Comment: I tried to use size classes but unfortunately there isn't a size class for portrait vs landscape iPad screen sizes. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
I also attempted to work with lower priority constraints. essentially I pinned the views to their closest edge and made those lower priority than the spacing between them (which was a greater than or equals to constraint). It would work for initial screen loading but if the orientation switched they priority would throw everything off. 
The best solution I believe is programmatically changing the constraint but I found a solution for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the spacing constraint a constant value like 40, make it a proportional width constraint that is some small percentage of the width of one of the views it is installed between, or a small percentage of the width of the overall superview. That way, as the width of the screen gets larger (as in landscape orientation), the spacing proportionately gets wider as well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Daniel Hall's answer, I would also like to point out that you could also pin the leading and trailing edges of the two `UIView` you have to their parent view and each other.

For example:

First `UIView`: Leading Edge 10 points from parent view, Trailing Edge 40 points from second `UIView`

Second `UIView`: Leading Edge 40 points from first `UIView`, Trailing Edge 10 points from parent view

It should resize itself based on these auto layout constraints once you rotate your device. Of course with this method, you run the risk of having your two `UIView` stretched beyond accurate proportion, so use it wisely.